# How can we automate already installed ios app on device using robot framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, appium, robotframework, osx-mavericks

There are 2 main questions that I have.

1. We are currently having macbook with OS X (10.9.5), it is old indeed, but will it possible to use robot+appium+etc... with this OS? Compatible XCode app is v6.2 on this one. What I read on internet there's no actual information on which versions that works well.
2. We want to automate an internal app that is already installed on iphone (OS 10.3.3), is this possible to automate by knowing its bundleid? One of the parameter for open application is app (fill in the location). Can we disregard this value?

If anyone can pin point me to the possible answer, it would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first question answer : i don't think MAC OSX version would be a problem for you, especially when you have a compatible Xcode app

Second question :
You can automate any app installed in phone (ios/android) with the information of  desired capabilities. Here is a sample code to open an installed app in ios

```
    *** Settings ***
    Library    AppiumLibrary   #you need to install this

    *** Variables ***

   ${APPIUM_SERVER1}       http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
   ${APPIUM_SERVER2}       http://0.0.0.0:4750/wd/hub
   ${app}    com.apple.mobilephone       #find package name of your app
   ${version}    version=9.3
   ${platform}    iOS
   ${deviceName}    ${destdevice}
   ${udid}    81eddea4d7f5cea5b5da65b999369b52
   ${platformName}    iOS
   ${name}     My First Mobile Test
   ${automationName}    XCUITest
   ${xcodeOrgId}    89E87VX
   ${xcodeSigningId}    iPhone
   ${usePrebuiltWDA}    True
    *** Keywords ***
    setup and open ios app
        ${iosdriver}=    Open Application    ${APPIUM_SERVER2}    app=${app}    version=${version}    platform=${platform}    deviceName=${deviceName}    udid=${udid}    platformName=${platformName}    newCommandTimeout=2500
        ...    name=${name}    automationName=${automationName}    xcodeOrgId=${xcodeOrgId}    xcodeSigningId=${xcodeSigningId}    usePrebuiltWDA=${usePrebuiltWDA}
        Set Suite Variable    ${iosdriver}
```

${app} is the desired capability where you provide package name, for more detail you can search how to find package name of ios apps.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Indeed we can start with our current macOS and using those example capabilities. What I noticed is that if the app is already installed, then we use bundleId instead of app :)